# Unable to change the virtual memory of Hadoop 2.2 to be more than the default 2.1 GB

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am running hadoop 2.2 in a pseudo-distributed mode on a laptop on CentsOS 6.4 with 8GB RAM.

Whenever I submit a job I get an error that says that the that the virtual memory usage exceeded , like below.

I have changed the ratio yarn.nodenamager.vmem-pmem-ratio in yarn-site.xml to 10 (10x 1GB) , however the virtual memory is not getting increased more than the default 2.1 GB , as can been seen in the error message below and the container is being killed.

Can some one please let me know if there is any other setting that needs to be changed ? Thanks in advance!

Error Message :

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1388632710048_0009_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Container [pid=12013,containerID=container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004] is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 544.9 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 14.5 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 12077 12018 12013 12013 (phantomjs) 16 2 1641000960 6728 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=15358 --webdriver-logfile=/tmp/hadoop-general/nm-local-dir/usercache/general/appcache/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/phantomjsdriver.log
    |- 12013 882 12013 12013 (bash) 1 0 108650496 305 /bin/bash -c /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN  -Xmx200m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-general/nm-local-dir/usercache/general/appcache/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/home/general/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/userlogs/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 127.0.0.1 56498 attempt_1388632710048_0009_m_000000_2 4 1>/home/general/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/userlogs/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/stdout 2>/home/general/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/userlogs/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/stderr 
    |- 12075 12018 12013 12013 (phantomjs) 17 1 1615687680 6539 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=29062 --webdriver-logfile=/tmp/hadoop-general/nm-local-dir/usercache/general/appcache/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/phantomjsdriver.log
    |- 12074 12018 12013 12013 (phantomjs) 16 2 1641000960 6727 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=5958 --webdriver-logfile=/tmp/hadoop-general/nm-local-dir/usercache/general/appcache/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/phantomjsdriver.log
    |- 12073 12018 12013 12013 (phantomjs) 17 2 1641000960 6732 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=31836 --webdriver-logfile=/tmp/hadoop-general/nm-local-dir/usercache/general/appcache/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/phantomjsdriver.log
    |- 12090 12018 12013 12013 (phantomjs) 16 2 1615687680 6538 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=24519 --webdriver-logfile=/tmp/hadoop-general/nm-local-dir/usercache/general/appcache/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/phantomjsdriver.log
    |- 12072 12018 12013 12013 (phantomjs) 16 1 1641000960 6216 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=10175 --webdriver-logfile=/tmp/hadoop-general/nm-local-dir/usercache/general/appcache/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/phantomjsdriver.log
    |- 12091 12018 12013 12013 (phantomjs) 17 1 1615687680 6036 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=5043 --webdriver-logfile=/tmp/hadoop-general/nm-local-dir/usercache/general/appcache/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/phantomjsdriver.log
    |- 12018 12013 12013 12013 (java) 996 41 820924416 79595 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx200m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-general/nm-local-dir/usercache/general/appcache/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/home/general/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/userlogs/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 127.0.0.1 56498 attempt_1388632710048_0009_m_000000_2 4
    |- 12078 12018 12013 12013 (phantomjs) 16 3 1615687680 6545 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=12650 --webdriver-logfile=/tmp/hadoop-general/nm-local-dir/usercache/general/appcache/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/phantomjsdriver.log
    |- 12079 12018 12013 12013 (phantomjs) 17 2 1642020864 7542 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs --webdriver=18444 --webdriver-logfile=/tmp/hadoop-general/nm-local-dir/usercache/general/appcache/application_1388632710048_0009/container_1388632710048_0009_01_000004/phantomjsdriver.log

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
```

Answer (score 1):

did you test changing

> yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb

or

> yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb

in yarn-site.xml?

I think this kind of properties would be helpful. check [yarn-default for the keyword "memory"](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)